# How to add Player Object Collision for aframe?

Tags: javascript, html, collision, aframe

I have done lots of research trying to find what I can on object collisions within aframe.
Other than object on object collisions, I haven't found anything.

Is there a way of producing player on object collisions within aframe, and if so is there a way of making a player object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a way of detecting collisions ([aabb detection](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/aabb-collider), [physics system](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system)) then you should add a collision mesh to the camera, and treat your player like any other object. The simplest way of adding a mesh to detect collisions would be adding a child object to the `<a-camera>`:

```
<a-camera myCollisionDetector>
  <a-sphere></a-sphere>
</a-camera>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1oycv73k/1/) (check out the console).

Comment: This was just what I was looking for, Thanks :)